# Getting the most experience out of a taxi

Tags: silkroad-online

I have started playing Silkroad Online again and as those who play it will know, the game doesn't really start until around level 70 (in my experience). My old accounts were deleted for inactivity.

I have never been a fan of taxis and have grinded my way through most of this game but now it seems to be the only viable way for such a short period of time. I was wondering, what is the best way to get the most exp out of a taxi?

I am aware of the level gap thing and stuff like that but what is the optimal level gap between your characters and the mobs that the higher level is farming? How many people in a party is suitable? Just stuff like that.

Thanks in advance for any information.